# object method can't be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, class, oop, object

I have the following code in a game called Uno.
Here is my code:

```
namespace Uno
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static Card[] stack;
    }
    public class Logic
    {
        public static Card[] addStack()
        {
            stack[104] = newCard(cn, rw1t);
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is:
In `Uno.Program` I have a variable called `stack` of type `Card[]` or an array of `Card`s.
In `Uno.Logic.addStack()` I want to reference that variable. 
But Visual Studio gives me this error in the line `stack[104] = new Card(cn, rw1t);`:
The name "stack" does not exist in the current context.

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: First thing: get rid of all those static variables. Start thinking in objects. Next: start giving classes more appropriate names. `Logic` says almost nothing. Next: give variables useful names - what is `r1` meant to mean? Next: start following .NET naming conventions. When your code is clearer and better organized, you're likely to have a better chance of answering your own question.

Comment: What @Jon said, but also, don't post such a large amount of code and expect people to solve your problem for you. Narrow down your problem.

Comment: `r1` stands for Rank 1. `Logic` is game's Logic. Removing one of the static variables will cause a more dangerous problem: in class Uno.Card variable r1 undefined.

Comment: Then, name it `rank1`.

Comment: Or name it `ranks` and make it in array or a collection... and it's not a matter of completely removing the static variables, but instead either making them local variables within `Main`, or make them instance variables within an appropriate class.

Comment: My code is short and concise.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've turned those variables constant in my new version of Uno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling `stack` from inside your `Program` class anymore, you're calling it from the `Logic` class.

the compiler doesn't know that it needs to look inside the `Program` class for `stack`.

the following shouldn't throw that error

```
Program.stack[104] = new Card(cn, rw1t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Program.stack[104] = new Card(cn, rw1t);
```

instead, since you are calling it from the `Logic` class.